# How can I fix the setting on IntelliJ? So that whenever I create a bracket and press enter, the caret goes in the center and formatted

Tags: intellij-idea

Please someone point me to the correct direction on how to edit the setting on Intellij.

I tried googling the same question online and going through the settings but I couldn't find it.

-- Whenever I create the curly brackets and press enter, the code doesn't get formatted like how it does on VSC.

```
/*Main Styling*/
html,body {
|}
```

-- Below is how I want my IntelliJ to format the curly brackets when pressing enter.

```
/*Main Styling*/
html,body {
   |
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Share the IDE settings: [1](https://i.imgur.com/gzBkykX.png) and [2](https://i.imgur.com/i81FvHv.png)

Comment: Hi Konstantin! This worked! Thank you so much!